# Running Flash on a headless Solaris box

Tags: linux, solaris, scripting, vnc

Our build server is a Solaris box, and I'm trying to run a suite of FlexUnit tests as part of the automated build process.

This works by compiling a swf movie with a suite of automated unit tests.  The build script launches this movie, which automatically begins running the tests.  Results of each test are sent back to the launching script across a port, and written out to a local xml file.  Once the tests are completed, the movie closes down, and the build script interrogates the results to see if all the tests passed.

The [FlexUnit wiki](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Continuous_Integration_Support) provides information about how to to acheive this on a Unix server, by using Xvnc to provide a virtual space for the flash movie to run its tests in.

I've provided this information through to our sys admin team, (along with the link to the article), and I've been told that because this is a Solaris box, we can't use that approach - Xvnc isn't supported on Solaris.

Unfortunately, I know very little about servers, *nix vs Solaris, or Xvnc.

Can someone please provide some advice about how we can achieve the same outcome on a Solaris box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xvnc is definitely supported on Solaris and is even bundled with recent releases: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0547/gghpo/index.html#6mgbdbssf

Comment: On releases older than Solaris 10 5/08, an alternative solution would be Xvfb, which provides a virtual display like Xvnc, but without the ability to connect to it via a VNC client.   That's been provided since at least Solaris 9.